# Etymology or genesis of the concept of proof

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-logic, logic

I'm wondering about the origin of the concept of proof in human thinking. Nowadays the concept is a cornerstone of mathematics, but also in law. Did early mathematicians maybe adopt it from the judiciary system of ancient civilizations?